# Compare text if shorter

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing comparmision between excel strings and word strings (within paragraphs), after delete all special characters froom excel strings and word strings i am doing compare. Unformtunetly looping through word paragrapphs and looking for specific match string excel has full string to be found but word sometimes not e.g:

excel string to be found:

```
Kodpocztowyimiejscowo34331winna
```

search paragraph for instance:

```
Ulicaulywiecka29Kodpocztowyimiejscowo34331winn ' missing 'a' in the end ...
```

My compare code here not working in such cases this line:

> If InStr(txt, search) Then

Unformtunetly sometimes word can cut some letters, do you know how i can update my code to be secure on that cases? See my whole code i got:

```
 Do
         ExcelField = ""
         X = X + 1
         ExcelField = EWS.Cells(RowNr, X)

         If ExcelField <> "" Then

         ExcelField = RemoveSpecialChars(ExcelField)

             If ExcelField = "KONIEC" Then Exit Do

 Dim search As String
     search = ExcelField

     Dim para As Paragraph

     For Each para In WordDoc.Paragraphs

         Dim txt As String
         txt = para.Range.Text  'whole word paragraphs
         txt = RemoveSpecialChars(txt) ' whole paragraph withhout special characters

         If txt <> "" Then    'sometimes in Excel columns are nulls we go next
         If InStr(txt, search) Then       

             EWS.Cells(5, X).Interior.ColorIndex = 4  'green marked
             Exit For 'field found in word exit and next
         Else
             EWS.Cells(5, X).Interior.ColorIndex = 3  'red marked '                                Exit For 'field found in word exit and next

         End If
         End If

     Next

         End If

     Loop Until EWS.Cells(RowNr, X) = "KONIEC"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide how many characters have to match from the left of the text. So if you decide that, say, 20 are enough then use:

```
If InStr(txt, Left(search,20)) Then
```

For a case-insensitive comparison:

```
If InStr(1, txt, Left(search,20), vbTextCompare) Then
```

---

You might, for example, check the first x characters, but base it on the original length of the search string. For example,

```
If Len(search) > 20 Then
    search = Left(search, 20) 'ignore after 20th character
ElseIf Len(search) > 10 Then
    Left(search, Len(search)-3) 'ignore last 3 characters
End If
```

You'll need to experiment to find the appropriate logic for your case.

Comment: and here is the point "How many characters..." good question because don't really know how to specify that as some of words are shorter, some longer, and there is sometimes cutted more (in my prev. example 1-a) /or nothing. What should be the way to prepare proper code?

Comment: Sounds like OP needs a regex.

Comment: @ckuhn203 How would that help? OP, I've added to my answer.